# Can't serve HTML5 video through PHP on Safari/Mac (5.0)

Tags: php, video, html

I'm encountering a strange bug in Safari where, when I serve MP4 video through PHP (to obfuscate the file beneath the document root with a token-based authentication system), Safari for some reason fires the `<video>'s` onerror event, and the video never loads (I can't get any useful information out of the event object sent to onerror — everything is undefined).

When I access the PHP script directly (i.e., the video is not embedded in a page), the video controls appear momentarily before flashing to a QuickTime question mark.

When I access the MP4 file directly, it works as expected.

What's bizarre is that the embedded video works perfectly in the latest version of Chrome for Mac.

Here are the headers when accessed through PHP:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="test.mp4"
Content-Length:5558749
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Tue, 22 Jun 2010 01:24:25 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=29
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) mod_ssl/2.2.15 0.9.8l DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.13
```

And here are the headers when test.mp4 is accessed directly:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:5558749
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Tue, 22 Jun 2010 01:26:45 GMT
Etag:"1c04757-54d1dd-489944c5a6400"
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=30
Last-Modified:Tue, 22 Jun 2010 01:25:36 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) mod_ssl/2.2.15 0.9.8l DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
```

The only differing headers are: Accept-Ranges (which I don't think is necessary), Etag, Last-Modified, Content-Disposition, and X-Powered-By.

Not only can Chrome handle the PHP-served video fine, but when I use the same script to load the MP4 through a Flash player, it also works fine.  I just can't figure out what Safari is choking on.

EDIT: Also, when I change the content disposition to "attachment", Safari will download the MP4 file just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the interest of anyone who comes across this question, here's the explanation:

I asked what I thought was an unrelated question about another Safari-specifc HTML5 video problem: [Single PHP “exit;” statement prevents HTML5 video in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114406/single-php-exit-statement-prevents-html5-video-in-safari).

Ultimately the problem had nothing to do with a PHP `exit` statement. In fact the problem was that I was using a `$_SESSION` variable to authenticate requests, and Safari uses a separate process to handle video playback that does not have access to the same `$_SESSION` data (unlike, say, Chrome).

What was confusing was that both the original Safari process and the playback process requested the video file separately. I was only looking at the original request, which did pass the `$_SESSION`-based authentication, so I assumed it wasn't part of the problem.

Anyway, if you are using `$_SESSION` data to authenticate a request from an HTML5 `<video>` player in Safari, [check out the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114406/single-php-exit-statement-prevents-html5-video-in-safari/3125869#3125869).

Comment: Good that I found this. Thanks. This same problem seems to occur with current versions of Firefox 27 and IE 11 on Win 7. While working on Chrome 32.

Comment: so what is the solution??

Comment: @Geo I think I ended up using the query string to store state, since you can't use `$_COOKIE`/`$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried modifying the headers sent via php to match those sent by the direct file, then one by one removing them / altering them to see which it is yourself?

Comment: Exactly what I've been doing the last hour!  Messing with Etag, Accept-Ranges, Content-Disposition, etc.  No luck!  Honestly, I can't tell really what differentiates the two.

Answer (score 1):

As I've discovered yesterday the iPhone version of Safari defers the playing of an mp4 file to the quicktime player integrated in the iPhone. This player first fetches the first two bytes of the mp4 (to somehow determine keyframes I suppose). It uses the accept-range header for this. Then the entire file is requested, again using accept-range.

I was serving these mp4 files with the use of PHP aswell, and I discovered that supporting this accept-range header everything started working all of a sudden. It might solve your problems with the desktop version of Safari aswell, although that has always worked for me without the accept-range support.

Success.

Bob.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue on safari as well. I have a php script that streams mp4/webm/ogv to an html5 video player. Until a couple of weeks ago it was working fine in safari. It continued to work in every other browser and all of the request/response header info looked fine to me, although I kept getting a plugin-in failed to load error in safari. I eventually realized that since I had changed my virtual host to https and signed my own certificates with openssl, safari was blocking GET requests for media content. Moral of the story... if you are using openssl and developing locally, safari will not retrieve video data for you if it doesn't trust your ssl certificate.