# PHP File As URL Fails Video Stream

Tags: php, html, video, mobile, safari

I'm have a PHP file that contains HTML markup for a video. Instead of using a full URL in the src part of the source tags, I use a PHP file that contains code that renders the video file.

The PHP file name is appended by a random string of characters that serve as a key to the actual video file name. I store these values in $_SESSION so that the PHP file that is rendering the video file will know which file to look for. I also have it use cookies so that nobody can reuse the tokens.

This works great in Firefox and Chrome, but it fails for Safari and for all mobile browsers I have tried on both Android and iOS.

For the sake of simplicity, I stripped down the whole process to simply have the video rendering PHP file while the PHP file containing the HTML markup calls the that file directly without using unique tokens.

When I do that, sometimes Safari loads it (very slowly) and mobile is still a complete fail.

The pertinent part of the first file looks something like this:

```
<video>
<source src=\"/videofile.php\" type=\"video/mp4\">
</video>
```

The other file simply has this just to see if that alone works:

```
readfile('filename.mp4');
```

So, non-mobile Safari sometimes loads it (very slowly) like that. However, it always fails whenever I add anything else including storing the file name in a variable and calling the variable as a parameter in readfile(), whenever I use sessions, when I use cookies, and basically anything else.

I tried many other ways to break the file down into chunks since I figured that's why it won't play on mobile, but loading the video file directly into the source tags has no problem. The problem seems to lay with how I'm calling the video file.

I have no idea why it works with Firefox and Chrome, but it won't work for the others stated above. I am not sure what to do at this point. I am not even sure if I'm phrasing the problem correctly since all of my Google queries have failed to yield anything like what I'm talking about.

**EDIT:** I've added the full file code I'm using

First One

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_cookies',1);
session_start();

$mp4=uniqid(); 
$_SESSION[$mp4]='video.mp4';
$ogv=uniqid(); 
$_SESSION[$ogv]='video.ogv';

echo "
<div style=\"position: relative;padding-bottom: 56.25%;padding-top:35px;height: 0;overflow: hidden;\" oncontextmenu=\"return false\">
<video style=\"position: absolute;top:0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;\" height=\"540\" width=\"864\" controls>

<source src=\"/videorender.php?video=" . $mp4 . "\" type=\"video/mp4\">
<source src=\"/videorender.php?video=" . $ogv . "\" type=\"video/ogv\">
</video>
</div>
";

?>
```

Now for VideoRenderer.php

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_cookies',1);
session_start();

$file = $_SESSION[$_GET['video']];

$_SESSION=array();
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(),'', time()-42000,$params["path"],$params["domain"],
                                     $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);

if(!file_exists($file) || $file === '' || !is_readable($file)){
header('HTTP/1.1 404 File not found',true);

exit;
}

readfile($file);

exit;

?>
```

Comment: Did you compared the http headers between your php script and a direct embedding? On the other side: piping the vid file through php is a realy bad idea.. (performance)

Answer (score 0):

Did you compared the `http headers` between your php script and a direct embedding of the video file?

You have to sent `Content-Type:video/mp4` for example:

```
header("Content-Type:video/mp4");
```

The `Content-Length` header is also a good idea:

```
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($videoFile));
```

There are several other circumstances like some browsers send more then one requests. See a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3125869/2797243

**On the other side: Piping a video file through php is a realy bad idea (server performance)** like you described. With this approach you will get no solution that will satisfy you.

If you want to implement something like authorization for ex., best approach is using a streaming server. Regardless the video is being streamed or will be provided as a progressive download.

The only solution I can think of, is to make `http redirect` to the video file. But I guess this could also fails, specially on the native players like the mobile ones.

Comment: The best results were indeed using that header. However, it simply made Safari load it slightly faster and slightly more often in non-mobile Safari.

Comment: @entropic616 Compare the complete `http headers` between a 'normal' embed and your solution with [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firebug/) for example and manipulate all header inforamtion like described above. I guess `Content-Length` is also necessary for ex. to get this work properly.

Comment: I just looked at that link you posted. I actually did notice that Safari was making two requests. The way I tested it was I used mail() to send me an email right after the file variable was loaded with the session token. I'd get two emails when I called the files through Safari. One would contain the file name and the other would be blank. I'm seriously considering just taking a different approach. I hear using web sockets can be quite useful for streaming videos.

Comment: @entropic616 Ty for your reply. Using web sockets for streaming vids is new to me. Would be nice to hear, if you will be successful with this approach.

Comment: I ended up doing it without the disposable php url. Also, I am using a conditional that looks at whether or not the user is on mobile. If they are on mobile, it will serve the straight up video file. If not mobile, the piping is working. Also, for Safari, I added a query string the php video source. videorenderer.php?type=stuff.mp4. This, combined with the video type header, seems to have helped the video to load successfully every time in Safari. It's still a bit slow, but I added .gif for when the video is loading.

Comment: @entropic616 ty for the feedback!